# Make a UDF accepting start date and end date. And returning

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions

Write an UDF accepting order date and ship date. Make the UDF return the number of sales orders (using Vista credit cards) that took place between the order date and ship date entered by a user.

(The table is `Sales-SalesOrderHeader` in AdventureWorks2012 in SQL Server 2012).

It looks like I have to reference `Sales-CreditCard` table to get the exact card name, because that is not provided in `Sales.SalesOrderHeader` table:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fx_SalesNmbr INT 
   (SELECT  OrderDate, ShipDate 
    FROM   Sales.SalesOrder  
    WHERE  CreditCardID = Vista (Maybe is should be a function @ Creditcardname)
```

Can someone, please, show me how it is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fx_SalesNmbr 
(
  @pOrderDate DATETIME, 
  @pShipDate DATETIME,
  @pCardType NVARCHAR(50)
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @result INT
  SELECT
    @result = COUNT(*)
  FROM
    Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS soh    
    JOIN Sales.CreditCard AS cc 
      ON soh.CreditCardID = cc.CreditCardID
  WHERE
    cc.CardType = @pCardType 
    AND soh.OrderDate = @pOrderDate 
    AND soh.ShipDate = @pShipDate

  RETURN @result  
END  
GO

SELECT dbo.fx_SalesNmbr ('2001-07-01', '2001-07-08', 'Vista')
```

Comment: _____ _           _      __ __         
|_   _| |_ ___ ___| |_   |  |  |___ _ _ 
  | | |   | .'|   | '_|  |_   _| . | | |
  |_| |_|_|__,|_|_|_,_|    |_| |___|___| THANK YOU, JohnS. I have run the script, and it works. The 'JOIN'portion is where I need to get into and learn very well. I appreciate the insight.